# SPServices loading but not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, spservices

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
        async: false,
        debug: true,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            console.log($.fn.jquery);
            console.log(xData.responseXML);
            console.log(xData.responseXML.xml);
        }
    });
```

I am having a problem with SPServices not working on our dev server. It works fine on prod and testing but not on dev for some reason. If I run the code above I get the following in the console.

{readyState: 0, responseXML: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "No Transport"}

I read online this can be a problem with cross domain transfers so I set the following:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

With that I now get the following:

{readyState: 0, responseXML: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "Error: Invalid Argument"}

I think this is because the SPGetCurrentUser call is always just returning an empty string for some reason instead of the user. Has anyone seen this behavior before? What are common things that can cause SPServices to load but not be able to execute calls? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since you're not on SharePoint 2007, you should consider using the [JavaScript Object Model](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sharepoint/1316/working-with-javascript-client-object-model-jsom) available in SP2010+. Between that and the REST services, I haven't seen many use cases for SPServices since 2010 came out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thriggle but unfortunately CSOM in SP2010 is quite half baked as you can't retrieve SP groups by name, only by ID in SP2010. This is a problem because I don't have a way to guarantee that the group IDs I am interested in will be the same across our different servers (prod, dev, staging etc.) So maintaining which ID's are relevant on which servers becomes a nightmare. You are totally right though 2013 and beyond CSOM is fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So turns out this appears to be a bug with SPServices. It appears that when you use SPServices on a site with a port number for some reason it duplicates the port number and so everything breaks. So as in my example above I did not specify the webURL and so SPServices used the current web but duplicates the port as shown here:

> correct url: http://yourserver:123/sites/yoursite
>
> SPServices: http://yourserver:123123/sites/yoursite

To fix this simply specify a site relative webURL as shown in the working code below. Hopefully this saves someone some aggravation.

```
var site = "/sites/yoursite";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
                           webURL: site
                       }),
        webURL: site,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //Do stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your post. Actually i got statusText:"Network Error" when i try to get the user groups using jquery in sharepoint. After passing the site url to the site variable like above code. my issue got resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.